# "View more [accounts]" link on user profile page is HTTP

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks, ssl

[image]

The "View more" link below the list of accounts on user profile is HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Other stackexchange.com links are also HTTP, for example link to the network profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just pushed a change that squashes the remaining http:// links to stackexchange.com from Q&A. Going live with the next production build.