# Link to reputation league from profile page is HTTP

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, ssl

The link to reputation leagues from the [Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) and [Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) tabs are HTTP.

[image: Link to Leagues]

Comment: Bah. I thought I got all of the se.com links [earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297442/155160). Apparently not.

Comment: @AdamLear and yet I can find another one by looking for "http:" in the source code: the link to _advertising info_ is _http://stackexchange.com/mediakit_ or in the [tour] the links to _Specific issues with the software that powers the Stack Exchange network_.

Comment: @fedorqui Mmhmm. I did a literal search for `http://stackexchange.com` in the views and fixed up all of that. Looks like I shouldn't have assumed that those would be the only file type to look at, though. I'll take another pass at it tomorrow.

Comment: @fedorqui : The link for the _advertising info_ in the Stack Overflow footer is `https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise`, other than SO sites the link is `http://stackexchange.com/mediakit`

Comment: Arulkumar: yes, in fact `http://stackexchange.com/mediakit` redirects to `https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise` so probably the _advertising info_ link should be updated to SO business.

Comment: @Arulkumar off-topic, but please read the comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297402/295232) about the HTTPS edits.

Comment: @Glorfindel : Thanks for the information :), I will follow the _Protocol-relative URL_ in the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The league link is fixed. (There's also caching at play, though, so it'll take some time to update on recently viewed profiles.)

I also corrected the links in the /tour here on MSE and "advertising info" in the footer.

Comment: In the [`/tour`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) page itself there is another `http://`, [that was not corrected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgaV2.png).

Comment: @Arulkumar Fixed.